# Nginx listening on 80 after removing server block

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, http

I am trying to restrict http access to my webapp. It should only be accessed using https.

my nginx conf file looks like this:

```
server {
  listen                443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate       /home/ubuntu/certificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /home/ubuntu/private.key;

  server_name ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.xx-xx-x.compute.amazonaws.com;
  
  # location blocks below ...
}
```

When I access my server using IP address and HTTP, it is redirecting users to https:// on chrome, but on firefox, it's redirecting to https://. I want to disable redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. How do I do that?

Update: Clearing browser cache resolved this. Can I restrict access to my server using EC2 DNS? I only have SSL for my IP.

Comment: You have not shown any nginx configuration containing a redirect. Why do you believe that this has anything to do with nginx?

Comment: So I had a redirect block from http to https but removed it after testing. It's still redirecting even though I removed that block.

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: Thank you, that was it!

Comment: Is it possible to prevent access to my server only using IP and not EC2 DNS? I need this because I only have SSL for my IP.

Comment: Please open a new question, and try to clarify it, the question above is difficult to understand.